# No idea why the loop tool is not working here

Tags: add-on

[image: Not working properly, any suggestions?]

---

No idea what's wrong here. It is just deforming in a strange way and I have no idea why.

Comment: The result is not strange, rather stretched would fit the situation, as such I can say that most certainly the reason is not applied scale. Changing the scale in object mode does that, rather use edit mode. To fix this you can (before trying the circle) press 'Ctrl'+'A' and apply the 'Scale'. Helpful link [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data/63193#63193)

Comment: Thanks Xylvier!